To remove the section title at the end of the article
The problem is shown in the picture. I want to remove the title section 1.1 above the next section. I don't know the reason in this book class template as I am new to TeX.

Below is the code in the preamble:
% \usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}   % Better typography

\usepackage{lettrine}   % Add drop caps to chapter openings
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[fontsize=10.5pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\kern 1pt}    % for nested quotation marks

\usepackage{pgfornament-han}

\setlength\columnsep{0.5cm}
% \columnseprule=1pt

% Paragraph formatting
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.45}      % Allow paragraphs to breathe by spreading the lines further
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}                   % Fixed space between paragraphs (i.e. disable variable parskip)
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

% Don’t add extra space after sentences
\frenchspacing

% Reduce widows/orphans
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000

% Page size
\usepackage[
    paperheight=210mm,
    paperwidth=148mm,
    top=2.75cm,
    bottom=2.55cm,
    outer=2.55cm,
    inner=2.55cm,
]{geometry}

% Reduce overfull \hbox{} warnings
\sloppy

% Contents page
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\large\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}

% chapter headings
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage[center,sc]{titlesec}

% headers/footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{-3mm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf[CFE,CFO]{\thepage}         % Set page numbers in the footer
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}        % Set page numbers in the left/right sides of the header
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark} % Author name in middle of left-side page header
\fancyhead[CO]{\rightmark}  % Book title in middle of right-side page header

\xeCJKsetup{CheckSingle=true}
\xeCJKsetup{LongPunct-={…}, MiddlePunct+={…}}
\xeCJKsetkern{…}{…}{0.2em}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

As for the main text:
\documentclass[12pt,openright]{book} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}

\title{\booktitle}
\author{\authorname}

\usepackage{misc/options} % the preamble part

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\rightmark\section{Something A}

\begin{center}
    Author A
\end{center}
 
\lipsum

\newpage

\rightmark\section{Something B}

\begin{center}
    Author B
\end{center}
 
\lipsum

\newpage
\end{document}



Well, TeX does what you tell it to do, and you are writing \rightmark\section{...}.  I don't quite know what you expect that to do.  Anyway, the first \rightmark is empty, so you don't really see anything, but the second one prints the line you are complaining about.

Thanks! I thought the \rightmark was to modify the headers and footers... I mistake it.
